# Why does browser zoom cause line artifacts in my web css html element

Tags: html, css

In a css/html element on a webpage I've made, if a user zooms in or out on their browser, artifacts emerge showing a line. [Here is a code pen](https://codepen.io/ryansutc-the-flexboxer/pen/MWBXqmz?editors=1100) of the issue. Zoom in or out on your browser to see the red line at top emerge like below:

[image: artifact on html element color]

I've read that these problems can emerge because a browser can set the zoom to 1.5x, thus creating rounding issues for pixels. See [slack post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6859217/6253707). But I'm not sure what the appropriate fix should be. In my case I want the triangles at each end of my rectangle element which I create via css styling. Besides recreating the graphic via svg, is there any good tricks?

Here is the html/css in codepen:

```css
#root {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 24px;
  max-width: 400px;
  float: center;
  position: relative;
}

#gridRoot {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  align-content: center;
}

#LegendContainer {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#container {
  background-color: grey;
  postion: relative;
  height: 120px;
  justify-content: center;
  left: calc(50% - 60px);
  text-align: center;
  top: calc(50% - 60px);
}

#circle {
  transform: rotate(7.39deg);
}

#jss {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  top: 40px;
  width: 110px;
  opacity: 80%;
  height: 20px;
}

#jss::before {
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  border-top: 10px solid white;
  border-left: 10px solid #00007f;
  border-bottom: 10px solid white;
}

#jss::after {
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 10px solid white;
  border-left: 10px solid #7f0000;
  border-bottom: 10px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div id="gridRoot">
    <div id="LegendContainer">
      <div id="container">
        <div id="circle">
        </div>
        <div id="jss">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't replicate on your link. Latest chrome on win10

Comment: I've been able to replicate on all browsers I've tested: Chrome: 109.0, FF: 109.0, Edge: 109.0.

Comment: I get the same behaviour

Comment: Why do you have so many divs

Comment: I started by reproducing a realworld example in an app I work on. This was a simplification but perhaps I could have worked to simplify further and retain the core problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ::before and ::after elements seemed to be causing the issue. Solution;

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 120px;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

#jss {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  width: 110px;
  opacity: 80%;
  height: 20px;
}

#jss-internal {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}

#jss-before {
  content: '';
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  border-top: 10px solid white;
  border-left: 10px solid #00007f;
  border-bottom: 10px solid white;
}

#jss-after {
  border-top: 10px solid white;
  border-left: 10px solid #7f0000;
  border-bottom: 10px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div id="LegendContainer">
    <div id="container">
      <div id="circle">
      </div>
      <div id="jss">
        <div id="jss-before">
        
        </div>
        <div id="jss-internal">
          
        </div>
        <div id="jss-after">
        
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I should have started with those selectors. Instead I was thinking it was a combination of relative positioning in some form.

Comment: After looking into it, I think the crux of this solution is that it allows removal of 'display: absolute' styling from the `before` and `after` elements.